# Magento 2 code review

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend, multistore, seo

I built a module that supposed to solve the following issue:
A multi-site setup with some CMS pages that are shared across the different websites. The problem that we are having is that this is causing duplicate content issues and affecting the SEO rankings. As well I have to add a new config in the admin area which will be filled with store language that is different than magento language for example "en-us" and "en-gb" this because the meta tag must have specific values for each country.

The meta tag will be structures as follows:

link rel="alternate" hreflang="' . $storeLanguage . '" href="' . $baseUrl . $cmsPageUrl . '" /

I have uploaded the code to GitHub repo:

https://github.com/AAbbadi/M2-Language

I want someone to let me know if this repo will solve the issue ? as well what is the best practice to solve this.

P.S: I'm Magento self learner. and I was unable to find someone close to me that can help me!

Comment: can you specify some more detail whay you are looking? Do you want to add store code into the URL?

Comment: Dhiren, thank you for your time reviewing this. I have updated this by removing the "<>" tags so now the link can appear, i hope this will help you